# No login possible after password encryption was implemented

Tags: spring, authentication, encryption, spring-security

I'm fairly new to Spring Security and I'm currently trying to implement password encryption, so I've added a password encoder to my `security-config.xml`:

```
<!-- Authentication Manager configuration -->
<authentication-manager alias = "authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref = "rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref = "userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash = "sha-256" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Once I've created a new user, the encrypted password is stored in the database. Here are the getter/setter for the password:

```
@Override
@Column( name = "PASSWORD", length = 128, nullable = false )
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword( String password ) {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();

    this.password = encoder.encode( password );
}
```

Well, pretty straightforward..

Let's assume that I've created a user whose password is `user`, in my database the encrypted value is stored, which is `cd85bb22c7b31d0101ba91ca42c953aa9ed0de92fa2b3a69fab9ff17e50ca0f22b7db6f3b90461ac` then.

**Problem**

My problem now is, that I am not able to login with the combination `user` (username) and `user` (password). My guess is that the password which is entered in the login form is not encrypted before it is compared to the password from the database.

What do I have to configure / implement to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't add unnecessary logic to your setter! Setters are called by Hibernate as well when the entity is being fetched (unless you are specifically using *field access*), which means that with every load of the entity the encoded password will get re-encoded.

Comment: Good point! Where should I place it instead?

Comment: Added comment to Abjhijit's answer. You need to do the encoding before calling the setter. Also remember to use the same password encoder as you have defined in your context config (e.g. use `@Autowired` to inject it to your service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do nothing!!

as Pavel said in his comment

> Don't add unnecessary logic to your setter! Setters are called by Hibernate as well when the entity is being fetched (unless you are specifically using field access), which means that with every load of the entity the encoded password will get re-encoded

Spring will automatically do the encode and decode when you configured the password-encoder as SHA 256

Edit: This is happening as you are mot using the passwordenocoder. can you try following

```
<authentication-manager alias = "authenticationManager">
<authentication-provider ref = "rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" />
<authentication-provider user-service-ref = "userDetailsService">
    <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
</authentication-provider>
```

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
     <constructor-arg value="256"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: Ok, I removed it. But when I'm persisting a new User now, the password won't be hashed and I'm able to login with the plain password. I created a gist with my Spring Security configuration here, maybe you could have a look, if I'm doing something wrong? https://gist.github.com/mhmpl/8073012 Thank you!

Comment: i am not too sure what you mean when you say you are able to login using plain passoword. what is happening is your password in stored as encoded and when you give the plain password spring knows that it has to encode and compare; so it is doing just that; and if it matches you are in

Comment: Sorry :) I'm creating a new user with username `user` and password `user`. The object is stored in the database with the plain password  (`user`) and not a hashed one. Even though I configured the password encoder I am still able to login with the combination `user`/`user`.

Comment: Sorry my bad.Editing my answer

Comment: You need to solve the use-case *setting new password* separately. Add additional logic to your service layer when setting the encoded password and encode it manually before calling the entity setter.